# React native styled component conditional Props

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I am using React-native typescript for my app. I am trying to make one custom setting screen. Custom Settings takes a data prop; an object that describes the content of  settings. In the setting screen few items are click able, it navigate to other screen or do some actions and others are un-clickable. I want to make styled components conditional render. If I use `onPress` props to the data then it will be clickable(touchable opacity) or un-clickable(View).

Currently I am using React native's `StyleSheet` and pass the `onPress` in `ContentContainer` element. If in data props `onPress` exist then it will will be `TouchableOpacity`, If not then `View`. It works fine and as expected. For learning purpose I want make this condition in Styled-components. But i don't how to do that.

**Here is code**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, TextStyle} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import {Icon} from './Chevron';

export interface RowData {
  onPress?: () => void;
  showDisclosureIndicator: boolean;
}

export const Row = ({
  onPress,
  showDisclosureIndicator
}: RowData) => {
  let ContentContainer = onPress ? TouchableOpacity : View; // This condtion I made
  return (
    <Container>
      <ContentContainer style={styles.contentContainer} onPress={onPress}> // In here i pass the onPress
        {showDisclosureIndicator ? <Icon /> : <View />}
      </ContentContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});


const ContentContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity` // I was trying to use Styled compoent. Don't know how
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to change TouchableOpacity to a View. It would make more sense to turn off the opacity and handle the logic in your onPress handler. You could also use TouchableOpacity's disable prop. `<ContentContainer disabled={!onPress}>`

Or you could use Pressable which does not go transparent on press so visually would be the same as a View. (A telltale sign that an app is React Native is when all pressables go transparent when you tap them)

As far as I'm aware I don't think you can change the type of view with styled components. You can absolutely pass props though to change the style.

```
import { TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import { Icon } from './Chevron';

export interface RowData {
  onPress?: () => void;
  showDisclosureIndicator: boolean;
}

export const Row = ({
  onPress,
  showDisclosureIndicator
}: RowData) => {

  const handlePress = () => {
    if (onPress) () => {
      // Do what you need to do on press
    }
    else {
      // Do nothing    
    }
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <ContentContainer
        isPressable={onPress}
        disabled={!onPress}
        onPress={handlePress}
      >
        {showDisclosureIndicator ? <Icon /> : <View />}
      </ContentContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

// lets, as an example, change background when onPress is true
const ContentContainer = styled.Pressable`
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ${({ isPressable }) => isPressable ? white : green};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found better solution. Just added disable if there is no any `onPress`

```
<ContentContainer onPress={onPress} disabled={!onPress}> // like this
```